# Howto upload/setup default.html page for Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

First, how to upload a file to blob root? It seems I have to upload file to a container (which is a folder IMO)

Second, if I finally found a way to upload file to root, will default.html page (or other name) become the default page for the domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a container named: $root.
Refer to ['Working with the Root Container'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh488356.aspx) for further info

AFAIK, blob storage cannot be used as a simple web server, so it cannot serve default.html.
You will need a web role instance for this.[Windows Azure Web, Worker, and VM roles demystified](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/windows-azure-web-worker-and-vm-roles-demystified/4017)

Comment: You're right in that blob storage is not really a web server, but you "can" use blob storage to host all content in a static website. What you can't do is set up a default page to serve, if someone visits your blob storage url without specifying an actual file (e.g. http://mysite.blob.core.windows.net). If you host default.html somewhere else, then all of your content links can point to static content in blob storage.

Answer (score 2):

There's a special container name, `$root`, that you use for writing to the root container. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh488356.aspx) for more information about this root container.

While you *can* store static web content in blob storage, there's no concept of a default object; that is, you can't have something like default.html be served when a visiter heads over to www.YourStaticSite.com. They'd need to visit www.YourStaticSite.com/default.html.

EDIT: As @SantiagoIT mentioned, you need to host your default page somewhere (such as a Web Role). Since you can move static content to blob storage (e.g. css, javascript, images, and static html), this will reduce the load on your Web Role instances (since requests to blob storage go directly to blob storage, bypassing your Web Role instances altogether). Even if your website is hosted on-premises, you could take advantage of blob storage, yielding the same advantages.

Going one step further: once content is in blob storage, you can choose to activate the CDN (edge cache). For frequently-accessed content, this could yield a performance gain for your end-users.

Answer (score 2):

Others have noted the $root container and also that there is currently no concept of a default blob.

I agree that it would be super useful to suport a default blob for each container including the root container.

I have an open feature request on this.
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/1180039-support-a-default-blob-for-blob-storage-containers#comments

Comment: I agree too, will go and take a look

Comment: @Qualcuno Even if this is supported, how would deep URL linking to work given that I am relying on IIS to route to index based on rules? This is SPA specific. Wondering how you could do this on CDN. My only file not on CDN is the index.html on my Azure Web App. But I would love to be able to serve that from a CDN. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the motivations to add $root folder to blob storage was to support Silverlight's clientaccesspolicy.xml file as explained in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: yepp, and crossdomain.xml file, and robots.txt file, and... lots of other files that need to be in root